# Paginate Classes State is duplicating it values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Redux:

```
.addCase(paginateStudentClasses.fulfilled, (state: any, action: any) => {
    console.count("paginate classes!");
    const { classes } = action.payload;
    state.paginateClasses = state.paginateClasses.concat(...classes);
    state.lastPage = action.payload.lastPage;
    state.isLoading = false;
  })
```

Component

```
 const classesRef = useRef<any>(null);
 const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
 const { user } = useAppSelector((state: RootState) => state.user);
 const { classes: studentClasses }: any = useAppSelector(
    (state: RootState) => state.classes
 );
 const { paginateClasses, lastPage, isLoading }: any = useAppSelector(
   (state: RootState) => state.classes
 );
 const [_page, setPage] = useState(1);
 const { handleScroll, loadClasses } = useInfiniteClasses(
    classesRef,
    user,
    _page,
    setPage
 );
 const [allClasses, setAllClasses] = useState([]);
 const [completedClasses, setCompletedClasses] = useState([]);
 const [notCompletedClasses, setNotCompletedClasses] = useState([]);

 useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(emptyPaginateClasses());
    loadClasses();
 }, []);

 const allClassesOfStudents = useMemo(
   () => studentClasses?.map((item: any) => item?.classes),
  [studentClasses]
 );

 useEffect(() => {
   setAllClasses(allClassesOfStudents?.flat(Infinity));
   setCompletedClasses(
    allClasses?.filter((item: any) => item?.classStatus === "completed")
  );
 setNotCompletedClasses(
  allClasses?.filter((item: any) => item?.classStatus !== "completed")
  );
 }, [studentClasses]);
```

Hook:

```
export default function useInfiniteClasses(
  classesRef: any,
  user: any,
  _page: any,
  setPage: any
 ) {
 const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
 // dispatch(emptyPaginateClasses());
 const loadClasses = async () => {
  try {
     if (user?.role === "student") {
      await dispatch(
      paginateStudentClasses({
        studentId: user?.clientId,
        page: _page,
      })
    );
   } else if (user?.role === "teacher") {
    await dispatch(
      paginateTeacherClasses({
        teacherId: user?.clientId,
        page: _page,
        })
      );
    }

     setPage((prevPage: any) => prevPage + 1);
     // setIsLoading(false);
   } catch (error) {
     console.error(error);
    }
   };

   const handleScroll = () => {
     if (
     Math.floor(
      classesRef?.current?.scrollLeft + classesRef?.current?.clientWidth
    ) === classesRef?.current?.scrollWidth
    ) {
      loadClasses();
    }
   };

   return {
    // isLoading,
    handleScroll,
    loadClasses,
   };
  }
```

I have created a custom hook for infinite scroll. When paginate classes is called it duplicates the data in redux state. I am calling the paginate classes inside useeffect in the components. I am using redux-persist so i considered that the problem was with the state saving in local storage. That's why i created empty class action to empty the classes before the loadClasses function is called. But it does not seem to be a problem.

I think the paginate classes is being dispatched for more than 1 time so it duplicates the data.

Will be very grateful if someone finds the answer why it is duplicating the data.